# How to add stored procedure in button properties in SSRS Report?

Tags: reporting-services

There is a stored procedure EmployeeDetails it is to update one table.

In ssrs report I have added a button and when I click this button, the button should execute Stored Procedure 'EmployeeDetails'. Now I unable to add this stored procedure in that button text box properties(Actions). Please let me know how to run that stored procedure when I click that button.

Thank You

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail.What does the SP do?, Where is the button on the current report (in a row cell, on it own, in a header etc)? What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

In the action redirect to the same report, with setting an internal parameter that you have call have been executed from the button.

This will refresh the data you require from the SP.